# How to use get MAX count but keep the repeated calculated value if highest

Tags: mysql, max

I have the following table, I am using MYSQL

```
BayNo   FixDateTime         FixType 
1       04/05/2015 16:15:00 tyre change 
1       12/05/2015 00:15:00 oil change  
1       12/05/2015 08:15:00 engine tuning   
1       04/05/2016 08:11:00 car tuning  
2       13/05/2015 19:30:00 puncture    
2       14/05/2015 08:00:00 light repair    
2       15/05/2015 10:30:00 super op    
2       20/05/2015 12:30:00 wiper change    
2       12/05/2016 09:30:00 denting 
2       12/05/2016 10:30:00 wiper repair    
2       12/06/2016 10:30:00 exhaust repair  
4       12/05/2016 05:30:00 stereo unlock   
4       17/05/2016 15:05:00 door handle repair
```

on any given day need do find the highest number of fixes made on a given bay number, and if that calculated number is repeated then it should also appear in the resultset
so would like to see the result set as follows

```
BayNo   FixDateTime           noOfFixes 
1       12/05/2015 00:15:00   2 
2       12/05/2016 09:30:00   2 
4       12/05/2016 05:30:00   1 
4       17/05/2016 15:05:00   1
```

I manage to get the counts of each but struggling to get the max and keep the highest calculated repeated value. can someone help please

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the fixes per day per BayNo
2. Find the max daily fixes per BayNo
3. Use the result from 2 to filter out the result from 1

Something like this:

```
SELECT fixes.*
FROM (
    #1
    SELECT BayNo,DATE(FixDateTime) as day,count(*) as noOfFixes
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY BayNo,day
) as fixes
JOIN (
    #2
    SELECT MAX(noOfFixes) as maxNoOfFixes,BayNo
    FROM (
        #1
        SELECT BayNo,DATE(FixDateTime) as day,count(*) as noOfFixes
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY BayNo,day
        ) as t
    GROUP BY BayNo
) as maxfixes ON fixes.BayNo = maxfixes.BayNo
#3
WHERE fixes.noOfFixes = maxfixes.maxNoOfFixes
```

You can run the repeated query (1) separately and store the result in a temporary table if needed.

I'm assuming the FixDateTime column is a an actual datetime or timestamp column. If it's not, you will need to use a different method to get the date from it.

Comment: Thanks, looking in to it.